# Weight based shipping , shipping charge per every 500grams

Tags: php, opencart

I would like to ask if there is an easy and flexible way to add stepped weight:price entries. For example there is an courier that charges as follows :

Up to 500 gram - Cost : HK$10

and from then and on for every additional 500 gram it costs HK$5 each.

First i would like to know if this kind of settings/logic is possible to implement in Opencart(2.0.1.1) and if it is possoble then
What is the proper formula to enter such kind settings page of
"Weight Based Shipping -> Rates" ?

Answer (score 2):

Use following code it will work for you

```
    $weight = 100; // total weight of your shipment
    $findWeight = $weight/500; //total weight divided by your weight
    if($findWeight > 1){
        $charge = 10; //basic charge
        for($i=1; $i < $findWeight; $i++){
            $charge = $charge+5;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $charge = 10;
    }
    echo "$".$charge; //total charges
```

Comment: I would add a isset(), to make sure it does not calculate the price if the weight is unknown or 0 and give a error. `$charge = $charge+5;` can be shortend to `$charge += 5;` if there is a need for it. +1 for the answer!

Comment: @Fairy Dancer , this is not the Answer i was expecting,  Its a normal Php logic you have implemented, 

By the way i found that there was inbuilt feature for weight base shipping, and it was implemented successfully by me.

Thanks